# Install caffe/pycaffe on MacOSX High Sierra

Tags: python, macos, caffe, pycaffe

I'm following this [tutorial](http://christopher5106.github.io/big/data/2015/07/16/deep-learning-install-caffe-cudnn-cuda-for-digits-python-on-mac-osx.html) to install caffe on my OSX High Sierra.

I followed all steps but I'm stucked when installing R-CNN example at this step:

```
$ make -j8 && make pycaffe

LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
ld: cannot link directly with /System/Library/Frameworks//vecLib.framework/vecLib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1
```

But the library veclib is present:

```
$ ls /System/Library/Frameworks//vecLib.framework/vecLib
/System/Library/Frameworks//vecLib.framework/vecLib
```

Can you help me please to solve this issue ?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. I installed Xcode 9.3 Commandline tool and changed cmake/Modules/FindvecLib.cmake to something like this and it works:

```
find_path(vecLib_INCLUDE_DIR cblas.h
      DOC "vecLib include directory"
      PATHS /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/
      NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

For my case, `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` must be set or there will be still link error.
You can also refer to [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindvecLib.cmake).